# What is the quickest way to find server on local network in Android

Tags: c#, android, networking

I have a .Net service that runs on a local network computer. On my Android phone I have to discover the server *as fast as possible* and get data from it.

I have considered these options so far:

- Scan each address and check if they respond - it takes about 30 seconds - NOT VIABLE
- Use the broadcast address to send pings - default Windows settings disable the ICMP ping, so it is unreliable - NOT VIABLE
- Use UPnp - Android discovery client is available, .Net device host not available, COM and ATL are way too hard to implement (no documentation, only interface guidelines - and it is mosty used by routers and NAS) - NOT VIABLE

What else should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I've eventually done it:

- The .Net service runs an UDP listener on a separate thread
- The Android client sends an UDP broadcast signal and waits for response
- If the response contains a specific message, it means a proper server

Using this approach, it works very quickly, takes 1-2 seconds to discover the servers.